# Putting PHP/MySql Results into Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I think I'm getting closer to understanding how to move my site towards a more PHP OOP approach.

I have different pages for each of my users because they all have different needs for a javascript generated grid. For maintainability, can I have one page and just inject php into the javascript as I (sort of) show below?? Is standard practice to just keep the php variables in MySQL and spit them out depending on the $_SESSION['user_id'];?? Just wondering if I'm on the right path with my thoughts so far?

```
ORIGINAL GRID
var mygrid;

            function doInitGrid(){  
            mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
            var combo=mygrid.getCombo(4);
            combo.put(2, 'Approve / Deny');
            combo.put(1, 'Approve');
            combo.put(0, 'Deny');
            mygrid.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");           
            mygrid.setHeader("Submit Date, Manufacturer, Product Category, Progress, Approval Status",null,["text-align:center;","text-align:center;","text-align:center","text-align:center","text-align:center"]);        
            <!--mygrid.attachHeader("#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter");-->
            mygrid.setInitWidthsP("10,16,44,18,12");
            mygrid.setColAlign("center,left,left,center,center");
            mygrid.enableAutoWidth(false);
            mygrid.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,button,coro");
            mygrid.setColSorting("str,str,str,str,str,str");
            mygrid.enableRowsHover(true,'grid_hover');              
            mygrid.setSkin("modern");
            mygrid.init();          
            mygrid.setStyle("font-size:11px;","font-size:11px;","font-size:11px","font-size:11px","font-size:11px");
            mygrid.loadXML("connector.php?hospid=<?php echo $hospid; ?>");
            mygrid.setColumnIds("date,man_name,group,approval_progress, approval_status");          
            var dp = new dataProcessor ("connector.php?hospid=<?php echo $hospid; ?>");     
            dp.init(mygrid);                        
            dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
            dhxWins.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");          
            mygrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function(id,ind){ 
                 if (ind == 0 || ind == 1 || ind == 2 || ind == 3){  
                dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
                var w1 = dhxWins.createWindow("w1", 60, 60,925, 575);
                dhxWins.setSkin("dhx_web");
                dhxWins.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");
                w1.centerOnScreen();
                w1.setText("");
                w1.setModal(false);
                theVar11 = (id);
                w1.attachURL("pop_details.php?var1=" +theVar11);
                return true;
                 };
                 });

MY IDEA FOR OOP GRID
    var mygrid;

                function doInitGrid(){  
                mygrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('gridbox');
                var combo=mygrid.getCombo(4);
                combo.put(2, 'Approve / Deny');
                combo.put(1, 'Approve');
                combo.put(0, 'Deny');
                mygrid.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");           
                mygrid.setHeader(<?php $MySQL_results ?>);      
                <!--mygrid.attachHeader("#text_filter,#text_filter,#text_filter");-->
                mygrid.setInitWidthsP("<?php $MySQL_results ?>");
                mygrid.setColAlign("<?php $MySQL_results ?>");
                mygrid.enableAutoWidth(false);
                mygrid.setColTypes("<?php $MySQL_results ?>");
                mygrid.setColSorting("<?php $MySQL_results ?>");
                mygrid.enableRowsHover(true,'grid_hover');              
                mygrid.setSkin("modern");
                mygrid.init();          
                mygrid.setStyle("<?php $MySQL_results ?>");
                mygrid.loadXML("connector.php?hospid=<?php echo $hospid; ?>");
                mygrid.setColumnIds("date,man_name,group,approval_progress, approval_status");          
                var dp = new dataProcessor ("connector.php?hospid=<?php echo $hospid; ?>");     
                dp.init(mygrid);                        
                dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
                dhxWins.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");          
                mygrid.attachEvent("onRowSelect", function(id,ind){ 
                     if (ind == 0 || ind == 1 || ind == 2 || ind == 3){  
                    dhxWins = new dhtmlXWindows();
                    var w1 = dhxWins.createWindow("w1", 60, 60,925, 575);
                    dhxWins.setSkin("dhx_web");
                    dhxWins.setImagePath("../codebase/imgs/");
                    w1.centerOnScreen();
                    w1.setText("");
                    w1.setModal(false);
                    theVar11 = (id);
                    w1.attachURL("pop_details.php?var1=" +theVar11);
                    return true;
                     };
                     });
```

Comment: Whitespace is your friend. Break up that wall of code a bit with some blank lines; it'll make it more readable if you group specific portions of it together.

Comment: `<!--` for commenting out JS? Ouch...

Comment: @Marc B Thanks for pointing that. Didn't even know it was a problem. I figured as long as it was grayed out on my editor I was good to go. I'll look at what is more acceptable. Trying to learn as fast as I can.

Comment: In js, there's `//` for single line, and the classic C-style `/* ... */` for multi-line. `<!--` is accepted as a comment in JS, but only for backwards compatibility with ancient JS-unaware browsers. The matching `-->` is NOT supported in js and actually has to be commented out as `//-->`.

Comment: Wow, downvotes for that question due to lack of whitespace? I was just trying to save room. Tough crowd.

Comment: @Marc B Thanks again! I may of gone years not knowing that. Very helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, (and others may feel free to disagree) what you propose is a perfectly viable option. If you'd rather not include so much php in your javascript, you can use the php `json_encode()` function to create an initial javascript object, and use it's properties instead of php echoes. Something like this for example:

```
var gridOpts = <?php echo json_encode($MySQL_results);?>;
mygrid.setColTypes(gridOpts.colTypes);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. This can open a whole new world for me as a newbie programmer. And like I asked above, I dont understand why someone would json_encode prior to placing variables vs. just placing php in javascript?

Comment: well, most of the time it's just easier to work with as a javascript object, and can save you some typing. Once again, there's nothing wrong with your approach, I was just suggesting an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I can't read that code, it's too messy...

But for general use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var js_variable = <?php echo json_encode($php_variable); ?>;
</script>
```

This method allows you to pass any type of PHP variable (except Resources) through to JS.

Comment: Sorry for messy code. I'm new to PHP and VERY new to javascript. Thank you for your advice and why create js variable first vs. just injecting php variable into the javascript? Wont it work either way?